# Regarding Alert View

Tags: iphone

I am developing one iphone app,  when i am clicking on a button i want to show one view which will take the user value for this i am using alert view instead of simple UIView so is it ok to use it b'cos,

I heard if i am using alert view then app will rejected on itunes is this true or we can use alert view.

Thanks & Regards,
Priyanka.

Comment: 1. Use proper english
2. Don't make us guess what you question is, questions have a question mark at the end of the sentence.
3. Accept some answers to your previous questions
Afterwards I will be glad to help if I know an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Priyanka as per your problem it seems when the alert view is popped up you want  to  get some data from user  right, so you can do that by taking textfield into uialert view and apple does allow what i said .

Hope this helps.